# HttpWebRequest Login return just Login Page

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I try to Login on KissAnime.com with a HttpWebRequest, but the response is just the login Page...

```
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.kissanime.com/Login");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0 Cyberfox/35.0";
request.Referer = "http://www.kissanime.com/Login";
String post = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}&chkRemember=on&redirect=", uname, pw);

Byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post);
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
dataStream.Close();

response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader streamr = new StreamReader(dataStream);
String sourcePage = streamr.ReadToEnd();

System.IO.File.WriteAllText("testp.txt", sourcePage);
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Loaded");
if (sourcePage.Contains("<span style=\"color: #888\">Hi</span>"))
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Success");
}
```

My goal is, as you might have guessed, to get logged in on the site...

Comment: Maybe you are missing some cookies?

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Using HttpWebResponse to login to websites and scrape information can get super tricky really fast. This particular website seems to have some kind of ddos (?) protection when you first visit which returns a 503 Unavailable error and forces you to wait a few seconds before it redirects you to the "real" page you want to visit. Long ago I built some functions to use for doing this work and I have been slowly improving upon them as new scenarios like this crop up.  The trick here is to get past the first 503 error, save the cookies and pass them back with each GET or POST request. I'm not much of a C# developer so my original functions are all written in VB.Net but after taking the time to convert them it all seems to work fine in C# as well. Try this code out and let me know if you have any further questions:

**NOTE 1:** Don't forget to change `USERNAMEHERE` and `PASSWORDHERE` with your real username and password.

**NOTE 2:** The `UrlEncode` function was a lot cleaner in VB.Net without all the case statements. If you don't want to use my function you could always include a reference to `System.Web` and use the `HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode` method that is built in there.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string sUsername = "USERNAMEHERE";
        const string sPassword = "PASSWORDHERE";
        const string sUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0";
        const string sMainURL = "http://kissanime.com";
        const string sCheckLoginURL = "http://kissanime.com/Login";

        private CookieCollection oCookieCollection = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartScrape();
        }

        private void StartScrape()
        {
            try
            {
                string[] sPostData = new string[6];

                sPostData[0] = UrlEncode("username");
                sPostData[1] = UrlEncode(sUsername);
                sPostData[2] = UrlEncode("password");
                sPostData[3] = UrlEncode(sPassword);
                sPostData[4] = UrlEncode("redirect");
                sPostData[5] = UrlEncode("");

                if (GetMethod(sMainURL) == true)
                {
                    if (SetMethod(sCheckLoginURL, sPostData, sMainURL) == true)
                    {
                        // Login successful
                        // Do whatever you need to do here


                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error connecting to main site. Are you connected to the internet?");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private bool GetMethod(string sPage)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = default(HttpWebRequest);
            bool bReturn = true;

            try
            {
                req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sPage);
                req.Method = "GET";
                req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                req.UserAgent = sUserAgent;
                req.Accept = "text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
                req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
                req.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
                req.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "300");
                req.KeepAlive = true;

                if (oCookieCollection != null)
                {
                    // Pass cookie info
                    req.CookieContainer = SetCookieContainer(sPage);
                }

                try
                {
                    // Get the response from the server 

                    using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
                    {
                        if (req.HaveResponse)
                        {
                            if (resp.Headers["Set-Cookie"] != null)
                            {
                                // Save the cookie info
                                SaveCookies(resp.Headers["Set-Cookie"]);
                            }

                            using (StreamReader stw = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
                            {
                                stw.ReadToEnd(); // Read the response from the server, but dont save it
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("No response received from host " + sPage, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                            bReturn = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    // 503 Error. Some sort of ddos protection is my guess
                    // Find the refresh header which redirects after a short time

                    string[] sSplit = ex.Response.Headers["Refresh"].Split(';');

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(sSplit[0]) * 1000); // Wait the time requested by the refresh header
                    GetMethod(sMainURL + sSplit[1].Replace("URL=", ""));  // Redirect to proper page
                }
            }
            catch (WebException exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Network Error: " + exc.Message.ToString() + " Status Code: " + exc.Status.ToString() + " from " + sPage, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                bReturn = false;
            }

            return bReturn;
        }

        private bool SetMethod(string sPage, string[] sPostData, string sReferer)
        {
            bool bReturn = false;
            HttpWebRequest req = default(HttpWebRequest);
            string sPostDataValue = "";
            Int32 nInitialCookieCount = 0;

            try
            {
                req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sPage);
                req.Method = "POST";
                req.UserAgent = sUserAgent;
                req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
                req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
                req.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
                req.Referer = sReferer;
                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                req.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "300");

                if (oCookieCollection != null)
                {
                    // Pass cookie info from the login page
                    req.CookieContainer = SetCookieContainer(sPage);
                }

                if (sPostData.Count() % 2 == 0)
                {
                    // There is an even number of post names and values

                    for (Int32 i = 0; i <= sPostData.Count() - 1; i += 2)
                    {
                        // Put the post data together into one string
                        sPostDataValue += sPostData[i] + "=" + sPostData[i + 1] + "&";
                    }

                    sPostDataValue = sPostDataValue.Substring(0, sPostDataValue.Length - 1); // This will remove the extra "&" at the end that was added from the for loop above

                    // Post the data to the server

                    using (StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
                    {
                        str.Write(sPostDataValue);
                        str.Close();
                    }

                    // Get the response

                    nInitialCookieCount = req.CookieContainer.Count;

                    using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
                    {
                        if (req.CookieContainer.Count > nInitialCookieCount)
                        {
                            // Login successful
                            // Save new login cookies

                            SaveCookies(req.CookieContainer);
                            bReturn = true;

                            // At this point you are already logged in and cookies have been saved so any code after this is unnecessary unless you want to double-check the source code

                            string sSourcePage = "";

                            using (StreamReader stw = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
                            {
                                sSourcePage = stw.ReadToEnd(); // Read the response from the server
                            }

                            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("testp.txt", sSourcePage);
                            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Loaded");
                            if (sSourcePage.Contains("<span style=\"color: #888\">Hi</span>"))
                            {
                                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Success");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("The email or password you entered are incorrect." + System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine + "Please try again.", "Unable to log in", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                            bReturn = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Did not specify the correct amount of parameters so we cannot continue
                    MessageBox.Show("POST error.  Did not supply the correct amount of post data for " + sPage, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    bReturn = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("POST error.  " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                bReturn = false;
            }

            return bReturn;
        }

        private System.Net.CookieContainer SetCookieContainer(string sPage)
        {
            System.Net.CookieContainer oCookieContainerObject = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
            System.Net.Cookie oCookie = default(System.Net.Cookie);

            for (Int32 c = 0; c <= oCookieCollection.Count - 1; c++)
            {
                oCookie = new System.Net.Cookie();
                oCookie.Name = oCookieCollection[c].Name;
                oCookie.Value = oCookieCollection[c].Value;
                oCookie.Domain = new Uri(sPage).Host;
                oCookie.Secure = false;
                oCookieContainerObject.Add(oCookie);
            }

            return oCookieContainerObject;
        }

        private void SaveCookies(string sCookieString)
        {
            // Remove commas in the expires date first so that we can properly parse the cookie string

            Int32 nIndex1 = sCookieString.IndexOf("expires=");
            Int32 nIndex2 = -1;

            while (!(nIndex1 == -1))
            {
                nIndex2 = sCookieString.IndexOf(";", nIndex1);

                if (nIndex2 > -1)
                {
                    sCookieString = sCookieString.Substring(0, nIndex1) + sCookieString.Substring(nIndex1, nIndex2 - nIndex1).Replace(",", "") + sCookieString.Substring(nIndex2, sCookieString.Length - nIndex2);
                }

                nIndex1 = sCookieString.IndexOf("expires=", nIndex2);
            }

            // Convert cookie string to global cookie collection object

            string[] sCookieStrings = sCookieString.Trim().Split(",".ToCharArray());

            oCookieCollection = new CookieCollection();

            foreach (string sCookie in sCookieStrings)
            {
                string[] sCookieStringSeparated = sCookie.Trim().Split(";".ToCharArray());

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sCookieStringSeparated[0].Trim()))
                {
                    string sName = sCookieStringSeparated[0].Trim().Split('=')[0];
                    string sValue = sCookieStringSeparated[0].Trim().Split('=')[1];

                    oCookieCollection.Add(new Cookie(sName, sValue));
                }
            }
        }

        private void SaveCookies(CookieContainer oCookieContainer)
        {
            // Convert cookie container object to global cookie collection object

            oCookieCollection = new CookieCollection();

            foreach (System.Net.Cookie oCookie in oCookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri(sMainURL)))
            {
                oCookieCollection.Add(oCookie);
            }
        }

        private string UrlEncode(string URLText)
        {
            int AscCode = 0;
            string EncText = "";
            byte[] bStr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(URLText);

            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < bStr.Count(); i++)
                {
                    AscCode = bStr[i];

                    switch (AscCode)
                    {
                        case 46:
                        case 48:
                        case 49:
                        case 50:
                        case 51:
                        case 52:
                        case 53:
                        case 54:
                        case 55:
                        case 56:
                        case 57:
                        case 65:
                        case 66:
                        case 67:
                        case 68:
                        case 69:
                        case 70:
                        case 71:
                        case 72:
                        case 73:
                        case 74:
                        case 75:
                        case 76:
                        case 77:
                        case 78:
                        case 79:
                        case 80:
                        case 81:
                        case 82:
                        case 83:
                        case 84:
                        case 85:
                        case 86:
                        case 87:
                        case 88:
                        case 89:
                        case 90:
                        case 95:
                        case 97:
                        case 98:
                        case 99:
                        case 100:
                        case 101:
                        case 102:
                        case 103:
                        case 104:
                        case 105:
                        case 106:
                        case 107:
                        case 108:
                        case 109:
                        case 110:
                        case 111:
                        case 112:
                        case 113:
                        case 114:
                        case 115:
                        case 116:
                        case 117:
                        case 118:
                        case 119:
                        case 120:
                        case 121:
                        case 122:
                            EncText = EncText + (char)AscCode;
                            break;
                        case 32:
                            EncText = EncText + "+";
                            break;
                        default:
                            if (AscCode < 16)
                            {
                                EncText = EncText + "%0" + AscCode.ToString("X");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                EncText = EncText + "%" + AscCode.ToString("X");
                            }

                            break;
                    }
                }

                bStr = null;
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            return EncText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All instances of a class that implements IDisposable need to be in `using` blocks. This includes the `StreamReader`, for instance.

Comment: Better, but you missed the `WebResponse`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I believe the code is better now. I assume you happen to know a lot of these IDisposable types off the top of your head because I'm finding it difficult to know which objects implement IDisposable and which do not. Apparently FxCop can detect these but I just tried it and it doesn't seem to do so by default. Either way, I read up on the `using` block for IDisposable objects and it makes perfect sense why you would want to do this. As I stated in my post I am slowly improving my `HttpWebRequest` functions and this just helps to make things better. Thanks!

Comment: This protection came up one day after i finished my first "Scraper", hopefully not because of me... You code looks similar to what i've tried til now to bypass the cloudflare protection, but a lot cleaner. But even with your code i get an error in the first exception from getMethod(), which i think is supposed to handle the 503 Error as you wrote in the comments. The Respone object within the exception is a null referenz and therefore posses no data.

And thanks for the Help Joey Joe Joe Jr Shabadoo and John Saunders.

Comment: @Soziapath I tested the code on another machine and it didn't work (although it always got past the `getMethod()`). I made some minor adjustments and it seems to work better for the 3 computers I tested on (all on the same ip though). Grab the code again and see if it works any better this time. If not, what is the exact error that you get and which line does it seem to die on?